# How to schedule a video with Youtube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'll like to programmatically schedule a video once uploaded via youtube API... I know the videoId.

Here is my code:

```php
    $videos = $youtube->videos->listVideos("snippet, localizations",
    array('id' => $videoId));

    // Since the request specified a video ID, the response only
    // contains one video resource.
    $video = $videos[0];

    
    $playlistItemResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->update("snippet, contentDetails, status", $video);      
    
    //$playlistItem:Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistItem
    $contentDetails=$playlistItemResponse->getContentDetails(); 

    $contentDetails->setStartAt("2024-12-24T05:42:08.000Z");
```

I'm getting an error that playlistItems->update requires a playlist not a video...

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Google\Service\YouTube\Resource\PlaylistItems::update() must be an instance of Google\Service\YouTube\PlaylistItem, instance of Google\Service\YouTube\Video given, called in /var/www/html/API/publishCompilation.php on line 217 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/YouTube/Resource/PlaylistItems.php:157
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/API/publishCompilation.php(217): Google\Service\YouTube\Resource\PlaylistItems-&gt;update('snippet, conten...', Object(Google\Service\YouTube\Video))
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/var/www/html/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/YouTube/Resource/PlaylistItems.php</b> on line <b>157</b><br />
```

How is the correct way of scheduling a single video?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that you are looking for [Videos: update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/update) endpoint and not [PlaylistItems: update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) one.

Comment: Videos:update do not have the method to schedule, the one that has it is Playlistitems:update